# Create a formula in spry to extract a data output if the columns match multiple custom fields

Tags: match, spry

How do I get a schedule result to extract a data set by matching 3 data sets? The current formula I have is as follows.

=ScheduleSum($A10, $D10&" & "&$E10, $H$3, $H$1,EC$7)